# Display a ListView in class View

Tags: android, listview, view, android-activity

Sorry I recreate my post and PLZ this time just answer if you know or have an idea about the answer, i'm tired about people answering "Why you do that ?" Or "Omg you don't know Android ?".

In my MainActivity (extends Activity), i want to call my class ListDataView (extends View) which displays a ListView.

Is it possible ? Don't ask me why i want to do that, just answer Yes or No and Why plz.

TY

ps : sry for my behavior, but really tired about some useless guys in this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want?

1. In your mainView show the ListDataView: You should check the fragments I think that it is that you really want to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example
2. Add a button (for example) to go to the other view: create a new activity with the new view and do an intent. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Yes i need 1, I found a solution with Class View : 

In MainActivity :
    ListDataView listDataView = new ListDataView(this);
        setContentView(listDataView.getListView());

And in ListDataView, i create my ListView from Adapter and return my ListView.

This is working but i can't control actions on row -.- 
I forgot about Fragment and this is also working and i can control my actions, i will continue in this way.

TY Fernando, great and fast answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

so you have one `Activity` and one view class called `ListDataView` that displays a list of data. and you want to set `ListDataView` as the view of your activity. Please correct me if my understanding is not correct..

You can create a object of your class `ListDataView` and set that object as the view of the `Activity` by using [`setContentView`()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) method as shown in the following code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListDataView view = new ListDataView(this);
        //may be some initialization of the ListDataView
        setContentView(view)
       }
```

Comment: This is it, TY Praful, it works but i can't control actions on row.  Anyway Thanks to Fernando i remember about fragments and i will continue in this way. TY ;)